# Confusion about "while(*s1++ = *s2++);" in C

Tags: c, pointers

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[]="bombay";
    char str2[]="pune";

    char *s1 = str1;
    char *s2 = str2;

    while(*s1++ = *s2++);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
}
```

**Output:(GCC Compiler)**

```
pune
```

But according to me output should be `puneay`. `pune` should be copied in place of `bomb` and rest should be as it is.

So, Why does compiler give an output of this code **"pune"** instead of **"puneay"**?

Comment: What do you think happens when the loop reaches the terminator of `s2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a null terminator at the end of the string which is also copied.

When null terminator is copied, while stops executing, and result is printed.

So memory at `str1` actually contains: `'p' 'u' 'n' 'e' '\0' 'y' '\0'`

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon after the while() statement, so it's equivalent to:

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++) {
    /* Empty loop */
}
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

So you're just copying s2 into s1, and then printing.  The copying operation *includes* the zero termination of the string, so you are copying:  'p', 'u', 'n', 'e', '\0' on each iteration.

Note that the assignment inside the `while` expression happens *before* while() statement is terminated.  If you're expecting "puneay", try this loop, which tests for zero termination before assignment:

```
while(*s1)
   *s1++ = *s2++;
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of sloppy code is unfortunately fairly common, when someone wants to copy strings in C using pointer arithmetic. The code is 100% equivalent to this:

```
*s1 = *s2;
while(*s1 != '\0')
{
  s1++;
  s2++;
  *s1 = *s2;
}
```

The purpose is to give a "poor man's `strcpy`". The null terminator is always copied into the destination buffer, which is why you get the output described.

Comment: I wouldn't call it sloppy, obscure, or anything else but terse. Admittedly using semicolon alone as empty statement without indentation is inadvisable. Anyway, the verbose equivalent you gave is right.

Comment: @Deduplicator Using either `++` or `=` together with other operators in the same expression is always sloppy, as both of those operators come with side-effects. Here we get both at once. Assignment inside conditions is widely recognized as bad practice since the early 1980s (see "Yoda conditions"). If `s1` and `s2` points at the same memory location, we get all kinds of bugs. If someone modifies the expression into lets say `while(*s1++ = do_something(*s2) + *s2++);` we get all kinds of bugs. Plus of course, the code is hard to read for anyone who isn't a member of the Obfuscated C Club.

Comment: Yoda conditions are an abomination, and a higher warning-level takes care of them. Yes, that needs additional parentheses to inform the compiler that things are fine. Pushing all kinds of additional things in there to make a point is disingenious. And what kind of bugs are there if they point to the same location? The target starting somewhere in the source (but not at the start) would obviously be a problem, but that's nothing to do with the specific code used.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed Yoda conditions were an abomination, as you say the correct way to deal with them is compiler warnings. Which in turn means that you can no longer purposely write assignment inside conditions! Because then you can no longer rely on that warning. Conclusion: one of the reasons why the posted code is sloppy, is because it has assignment inside a condition. Adding an additional parenthesis is nonsense, that's a really dirty patch which only works on one particular compiler, with no support whatsoever by the standard.

Comment: Suppressing a QOI-warning is not an issue for the standard at all. And on which compilers giving the warning doesn't that hint work?

Comment: @Deduplicator As far as I know it only works on gcc. The standard does of course not mention any diagnostics at all, since assignment in conditions is allowed.

Comment: Coliru says clang does it too: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb982d54da89c9cb Cannot test msvc or icc just now. Anyway, I would call the warning on any compiler not supporting that hint for suppression defective.

Answer (score 0):

`while(*s++ = *s1++)` copies also the string terminator `\0' as the assign operation is executed before the actual logical check.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by using this code:

```
while(*s2)
    *s1++ = *s2++ ;

printf("%s\n",str1);
```

Because (*s2) have the '\0' in the end of the string